# can't get this basic privoxy filter to work

Tags: proxy, privoxy

I am new to privoxy, I set it up, and added some filters, testing it, just to get a letter to change

s/a/g/g

s@a@f@g

s/a//ig

but the letter 'a' remained on web pages.

Comment: Your regexes look fine, are you sure that filter's being applied to all pages?

Comment: It wasn't a regex problem obviously. I sorted it out.. I don't recall the details 'cos I haven't messed with privoxy for a while but it was about getting syntax right in the filters and the action file.